# Wordpress register URL Mismatch

Tags: wordpress, redirect, authentication

In blog home page, when i click on register, it takes me to this URL http://www.tawnosdesigns.com/mockups/behindthestorywp/wp-login.php?action=register . This is not my site's (behindthestory) login page. it is another domain which i used for mockup. how can I set my original site (behindthestory.org) register URL ?

site url : behindthestory.org
username : gatsby
password : santoga

Answer (score 0):

If this happened after you deployed it, you can try going into the wp_options table in the database, and searching for the old options and changing them. I think the option is called `site_url`.

Comment: but my site is opening with its own domain, only this registration URL is redirecting to that website.

Comment: Even clicking on links on the site?

Comment: actually, you can see the register button at middle. when i click on it, it takes me to above link which is not the sites login url. it is a mockup i made before. now i want to set my sites login URL on that register button which may be behindthestory.org/wp-login like this

Comment: To me it sounds like its not configured correctly. I'd try checking the database or try seeing what steps you missed [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress).

Answer (score 0):

After visit your provided site, it's seems you are using you are using a static form on header or installed plugin for registration. So you need to change in template or check  plugin setting if you installed for registration.

maximum chance this is a static form in template.

Hope this helps you. All the best ;)

Comment: thanks for comment. so where, i mean which file i need to check if it is not any plugin. i also think it is static form.

Comment: many possibilities it's depend on your theme setting, here some listed;
1. page.php
2. front-page.php (if exist)
3. if you set a static page for Home page( see in admin Settings >> Reading >> Front page drop down), find that page name in Pages section and edit content.